# Does SQL INSERT involve any read/write lock?

Tags: mysql, insert, locking

This is an extremely simple question, but i really can't find any useful answer on Google.

I've been reading that there's a READ LOCK on SELECT, and WRITE LOCK on UPDATE statements. However, i'm trying to find out if there's any kind of LOCK when we INSERT into a table?

The assumption is that the table is using InnoDB as the engine.

Answer (score 5):

When inserting, InnoDB creates a so called "gap lock".

[The manual describes this quite well](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html):

> *A type of gap lock called an insertion intention gap lock is set by INSERT operations prior to row insertion. This lock signals the intent to insert in such a way that multiple transactions inserting into the same index gap need not wait for each other if they are not inserting at the same position within the gap. Suppose that there are index records with values of 4 and 7. Separate transactions that attempt to insert values of 5 and 6 each lock the gap between 4 and 7 with insert intention locks prior to obtaining the exclusive lock on the inserted row, but do not block each other because the rows are nonconflicting*

In addition to that, any *unique* index will be locked for the provided values to make sure that two different transactions don't insert the same value (that's slightly different than the gap lock if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

For innoDB mysql uses row level locking.
When inserting there is no row to lock because You are creating it.

Comment: InnoDB does create some locks (albeit not "row locks") when inserting.

Comment: It crossed my mind that there has to be some clever mechanism to avoid inserting two rows with same auto increment value just didn't connect it with locks...stupid me

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the gap lock description, Mysql INNODB does a ROW-LOCK on the row that is being inserted.